# android: Unable to load new activity from RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I can show a `Toast` in `onClick` event but unable to load a new `Activity`.

Here is my code:

```
public class AppointmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppointmentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentList;
    private Context mContext;

    public AppointmentAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public Button mView, mSend;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_view_appointment);
            mSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_send_appointment);

            mView.setOnClickListener(this);
            mSend.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.getId() == mView.getId()) {
         //       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "View ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(detailsIntent);
            }

            if (v.getId() == mSend.getId()) {
      //          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Send ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    /................./
}
```

This specific line of code doesn't work.

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(detailsIntent);
    }
```

When I run this application got `NullPointException`
Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you're absolutely certain the problem is from that specific line, then the only thing that can cause a `NullPointerException` is `mContext` being null

Comment: `NullPointException` means you are invoking something that doesn't exist. Post your stack trace completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mContext` variable is `null`. You need to check your code to see why this variable is `null`.

Since you said you can show a `Toast` use `v.getContext()`. To pass data use `getAdapterPosition()` to get the item clicked and pass the data in the `Intent`. Make sure `Appointment` class implements `Serializable` interface.

```
Appointment selectedAppointment = appointmentList.get(getAdapterPosition());
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
detailsIntent.putExtra("selectedAppointment", selectedAppointment);
v.getContext().startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Comment: Can you tell me, how can I pass data to new activity from current position ?

Comment: I think his context is null because when he is creating the adapter he is passing null. Eg: `AppointmentAdapter appointmentAdapter  = new AppointmentAdapter(null);`

Comment: @SrikarReddy Yes it is possible. But we cant confirm it since we don't have the code.

Comment: getting Error `java.lang.ClassCastException:com.sohan.propertymission.model.Appointment` cannot be cast to `java.io.Serializable` -help me plz

Comment: Make sure Appointment class implements `Serializable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

@sohanoor you can try to generate click even in onBindViewHolder..Hope this can help you..

@Override

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) { 

    String item = testItems.get(i).getTestname();     
    viewHolder.tvTestList.setText(item );    
    viewHolder.tvTestList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  
          Context context = view.getContext();    
          Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);  
          mContext.startActivity(detailsIntent);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do view.setonclickListner insted of mView.setonclicklistner